# Persisted queries in GraphQL in production mode

Tags: graphql

What library/server supports to do GraphQL simple(not restricted) queries in "dev mode", but in "prod mode" to use persisted queries instead of simple queries?

In "dev mode" we can be very flexible and not optimize queries, because in developing we do not need really fast queries.

In "prod mode" we can assign an id to each queries we have in application, so no need to parse queries every time, and we can write optimized queries to database.

Comment: John's answer is _general_, but is pretty much as good as it can be given that we don't know what server/client library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you could simply wrap the 'persisted queries' logic in a conditional based on being in 'dev mode'. For example, don't add the middleware to the server, and don't add the network interface on the client unless in 'prod mode'.